# Nginx config is not case insensitive to image files

Tags: nginx, drupal-7, case-insensitive

Images are only displaying if they have the correct case.  These need to be case insensitive please see my config file.

The image I have having trouble with works at:

http://domain.com/sites/default/files/vimages/imagename.jpg

but not at

http://domain.com/sites/default/files/vimages/imagename.JPG

> server {
>
> ```
>    listen 80;
>
>    server_name domain.com;
>    root /home/domain.com/www; ## <-- Your only path reference.
>
>    access_log /home/domain.com/logs/access.log;
>    error_log /home/domain.com/logs/error.log;
>
>    # Enable compression, this will help if you have for instance advagg‎ module
>    # by serving Gzip versions of the files.
>    gzip_static on;
>
>    gzip on;
>
>    location = /favicon.ico {
>            log_not_found off;
>            access_log off;
>    }
>
>    location = /robots.txt {
>            allow all;
>            log_not_found off;
>            access_log off;
>    }
>
>    # This matters if you use drush
>    location = /backup {
>            deny all;
>    }
>
>    # Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
>    location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
>            allow 192.168.0.0/16;
>            deny all;
>    }
>    location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
>            return 403;
>    }
>
>    # No no for private
>    location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
>            return 403;
>    }
>
>    # Block access to "hidden" files and directories whose names begin with a
>    # period. This includes directories used by version control systems such
>    # as Subversion or Git to store control files.
>    location ~ (^|/)\. {
>            return 403;
>    }
>
>    location / {
>            # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
>            try_files $uri @rewrite;
>    }
>
>    location @rewrite {
>            # Some modules enforce no slash (/) at the end of the URL
>            # Else this rewrite block wouldn't be needed (GlobalRedirect)
>            rewrite ^ /index.php;
>    }
>
>    location ~ \.php$ {
>            try_files $uri =404;
>            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
>            #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
>            fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
>            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
>            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
>            fastcgi_index index.php;
>            include fastcgi_params;
>    }
>
>    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
>            expires 52w;
>            add_header  Cache-Control "max-age=31449600, no-transform, public";
>            log_not_found off;
>    }
>
>    # Catch image styles for D7 too.
>    location ~* ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
>            try_files $uri @rewrite;
>    }
>    location ~* /sites/.*/files/vimages/ {
>            try_files $uri @rewrite;
>    }
>    # Fighting with ImageCache? This little gem is amazing.
>    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ {
>            try_files $uri @rewrite;
>    }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Why should it? Most unix filesystems are case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is working against the filesystem and has no control over the name of the files when serving from a directory.

If you want case insensitive you need to do a rewrite.

Comment: Following the instructions at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location shows that ~* makes the location case insensitive.  How would a rewrite work for directories /sites/.*/files/styles/ and /sites/.*/files/vimages/?